# Continue the `while` loop when ExecuteScript(setInterval) is finished

Tags: c#, javascript, selenium, scroll, selenium-webdriver

I have a code that scrolls a growing page to the bottom (until it's not possible to scroll to the bottom).
When it's not possible, it scrolls to the top and the javascript code is finished.

For example: imagine a timeline on facebook.
It's a growing page, so I can scroll it again and again until it's not possible to scroll (then I will be in: "BORN").

So this is my code:

```
while (i < elements.Count)
{

    js.ExecuteScript("var timeId = setInterval( function() { 
    if(window.scrollY<(document.body.scrollHeight-window.screen.availHeight)) 
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); else { clearInterval(timeId); 
    window.scrollTo(0,0); } },5000);");

    i++;
}
```

I want to add 1 to `i` only when the `setInterval` is finished.

I tried the next thing:

```
while (i < elements.Count)
{
    object a = js.ExecuteScript("setInterval( function() {  
    if(window.scrollY<(document.body.scrollHeight-window.screen.availHeight)) { 
    window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight); return '1'}; else { 
    clearInterval(timeId); window.scrollTo(0,0); return '2'} },5000);");

    while (a != '2') {
      // do nothing, this while will be ended when we arrived the bottom and
      // go back to the top
    }

    // all the page is loaded
    i++;
```

}

but it doesn't work.. maybe there is a way to scroll to the bottom more and more and then to the top without using set interval? (but remember: it's a growing page that grows when you scroll it down and down..

How can I do it?

Comment: Have removed C# Tag - it may be being used in the project as a whole, but is not relevant to the question.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Only the string is JS code... Everything else in the question is C#.

Comment: @Pluto, it may have been generated from C#, but this is ostensibly all about Javascript.

Comment: It's most definitely about C# as you are interacting with C# variables FROM javascript

Comment: You can't. At the moment the `setInterval` callback is executed, the `while` loop already terminated.

Comment: This is not javascript code. Looks like a testing framework or an embedded web browser to me.

Comment: Running the javascript in the browser scrolls the page down to the bottom (even if it's an infinite scroll page like the Facebook timeline) and then back up when there's no more content to load. Could you please explain in more detail why you are running it in a loop and what you intend to do with it?

Comment: Your JS code will be late in the run. I think, you should provide the full page code. This doesn't make sense. Facebook loads new content when/after you scroll the page; but your code does not listen to any kind of event. Where does "elements" come from? Why do you have a 5 sec interval?

Comment: Do you mean `if (a != '2') { continue; }` where `continue` means proceed to next iteration of the enclosing loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setInterval` function is asynchronous, meaning that it happens after the `ExecuteScript` function gets a return value, this is why what you tried didn't work. The best solution I can think of is to change a little bit the structure of your code and use C# Threading.

### Using C# Threading

This way, what we are going to do is to each time stop the code for 5 seconds and then execute a JavaScript code that checks if you can scroll further down, if yes scroll down and if not scroll back up. This JavaScript code will also return whether we should continue running this loop or not.

Basically, this is the JavaScript code we will execute:

```
if (window.scrollY < (document.body.scrollHeight - window.screen.availHeight)) {
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
    return true;
} else {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    return false;
}
```

And this is how the overall C# code should look:

```
while (i < elements.Count)
{
    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        run = (bool)js.ExecuteScript("if(window.scrollY<(document.body.scrollHeight-window.screen.availHeight)){window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);return true;}else{window.scrollTo(0,0);return false;}");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

find something to use as a variable for when you hit the bottom and then use an `if` statement in the `While` loop to increment `i` when that has happened